# phonegap open link in app browser does not work

Tags: android, phonegap-build, phonegap, inappbrowser

I build an Android APP by PhoneGap Build service(https://build.phonegap.com/apps)

I already add these into the config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"/>
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"/>
<allow-intent href="http:///"/>
<allow-intent href="https:///"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
```

And also add these to my HTML file

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    }
</script>
```

Finally...I have tried

```
<a href="#" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com/', '_system');return false;">link</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_system');return false;">link</a>
```

I also tried the option 'location=yes' which I found in some answers

But all of them don't work....Do I miss any step?

PhoneGap Android version:  cli-6.5.0, 6.1.2 and Android version: 7.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue. But after struggling a lot this is what fixed my issue.

First remove and re-add the InAppBrowser plugin,

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Then add the following to your **config.xml**,

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

Remember by this time, InAppBrowser have to be in your **plugins** folder.

Then the anchor tags in your app should look like,

```
<a id="to-recover" href="#" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');" >google</a>
```

**Note:** Due to a bug in Cordova Android 7.1.3, InAppBrowser doesn't work. Maybe that is the issue affecting you. So stick with either Cordova Android 7.1.2 or upgrade to 7.1.4

Reference:

[Android Class Not Found](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/355)

[Plugin doesn't install correctly](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/354)

You can specify the Cordova Android version while installing like this,

```
cordova platform add android@7.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this core phonegap plugins in your config.xml file you can visit this git repo https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-template-hello-world/blob/master/www/config.xml

Comment: Please update your question and include explanation how the suggested plugin addresses the problem stated in the question.